# How to make corners of PolyLineSegment rounded?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I want to create a window with irregular shape. I made something similar to what I want to create ultimately, but I want something with rounded corners. I read somewhere that it is not possible with PolyLineSegment, could you advise me how to create it? What object/collection of objects should I use?

```
    <Window   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="400"
                 AllowsTransparency="True"
                 OpacityMask="White"
                 WindowStyle="None"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 >
      <Canvas>
        <Path Height="250"
              Stroke="Gray"
              StrokeThickness="2"
              Name="UIPath"

              >
          <Path.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Aqua">
            </SolidColorBrush>
          </Path.Fill>
          <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
              <PathFigureCollection>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0"
                            IsClosed="True">
                  <PolyLineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True" Points="400,000"  />

                  <PolyLineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True"
                                   Points="400,200" />
                  <PolyLineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True"
                                   Points="180,200" />

                  <PolyLineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True"
                                   Points="200,250" />
                  <PolyLineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True"
                                   Points="100,200" />

                  <PolyLineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True"
                                   Points="00,200"  />

                </PathFigure>
              </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry>
          </Path.Data>
          <Path.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
              <MenuItem Header="Minimize"
                        Name="mnuInvokeMinimize"  />
              <MenuItem Header="Maximize"
                        Name="mnuInvokeMaximize" />
              <MenuItem Header="Restore Down"
                        Name="mnuInvokeRestore" />
              <MenuItem Header="Close"
                        Name="mnuInvokeClose" />
            </ContextMenu>
          </Path.ContextMenu>
          <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup x:Name="pathTfg">
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"
                              ScaleY="1" />
              <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
          </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
      </Canvas>
    </Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `CombinedGeometry` with a `RectangleGeometry` with rounded corners and a `PathGeometry` for the remaining part:

```
<Path Fill="Aqua" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,400,200" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M180,200 L200,250 100,200"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```